# How to find densitiy of |X|

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \operatorname{N}\left(0,1\right)$ be a standard normal distributed random variable:
Can someone please please show me the whole way how to find the density of $\left\vert X\right\vert$.

*My tries:* I saw sites where someone gives tips and I wanna do it with Cumulative distribution function but everywhere are only few tips and I didn't understand it. Can someone please explain how to do it for someone who never did tasks with densities before?

I only know the density of $X$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

I would be very thankful for help.

Comment: pretty sure this has been already answered many times

Comment: i said that i found sites with this task but there was never an answer that i understood

Comment: you should post more about your mathematical understanding

Comment: A standard normally distributed random variable has a symmetric distribution about $0$, so $|X|$ has zero density below $0$, and double the standard normal density above $0$

Comment: Notice $P[|X|\leq a]=2\int^a_0\phi_X(t)\,dt$. Hence $\phi_{|X|}(a)=2\phi_X(a)\mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}(a)$, where $\phi_X$ is the density $X\sim N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard normally distributed random variable has a symmetric distribution about $0$, so $|X|$ has zero density below $0$, and double the standard normal density above $0$

If you want to deal with CDFs, then if $Y=|X|$ where $F_X(x)=\Phi(x)$ then

- $F_Y(x)=P(|X| \le x)$

  - which is $0$ when $x <0$
  - and is $P( -x \le X \le x) = \Phi(x)-\Phi(-x)$ when $x\ge 0$
- the density is the derivative of this

  - $f_Y(x)=0$ when $x <0$
  - $f_Y(x)= \phi(x)+\phi(-x) = 2\phi(x)$ when $x\ge 0$

This is called a [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution)

Comment: ok so your phi(x) is the density of X right? and you got phi(x)-phi(-x) because of the integral? i think then i got it